# Remove Android Studio bundled plugin

Tags: android, android-studio, plugins, ide, android-gradle-plugin

Can we remove Android Studio built-in plugins, which are listed under `Bundled` view in Preferences? Or only custom ones can be deleted? If yes, how?

I want to free up some space by removing plugins I don't use.

Answer (score -1):

You can remove the plugins but please make sure not to delete the plugins which are recommended by android studio and for your project.

I hope you will get some help form the below link:

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html

Comment: How to remove them? There is no useful info on those link.